# Pandas dataframe sort on unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
df 

Col1     Col2
M1        4
M1        2
M1        1
M1        3
M2        3
M2        1
M2        2
```

I would like to sort the dataframe on python to achieve

```
Col1     Col2
M1        1
M1        2
M1        3
M1        4
M2        1
M2        2
M2        3
```

Any suggestion how to achieve this?  Thank you

Comment: `df.sort_values(['Col1','Col2'], inplace=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
>>> df = df.sort_values(by=["Col1", "Col2"])
>>> print(df)

  Col1  Col2
2   M1     1
1   M1     2
3   M1     3
0   M1     4
5   M2     1
6   M2     2
4   M2     3
```